# Javascript file caching

Tags: javascript, xml, caching, web

I am developing a solution to handle localization on our web product. To do this i save nodes of text in different languages in a XML file. I need to be able to get the values from this file both server and client side.
When i get the values serverside, i store them in the http cache so they will be faster to load next time they are requested. This is working very well.
Now, how can i do the same clientside with JavaScript? Right now i use JQuery to access the file and find the right node every time.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe if you build an array which loads the files in javascript then you can access that array instead of the files and they will be cached.  This is how image files are pre-cached in javascript so I would assume it would work for xml files as well.

Comment: That would be possible yes. But i forgot to mention that the way to cache this text, needs to be persistent. Meaning, that if the user goes to another page, the cache will still hold the values. I realise i could send the array on to the next page, but that seems a bit crude...

Comment: Perhaps you should look into using a cookie stored on the clients end then.  Sorry, I am not that familiar with cookies but it seems that would be the way to go if you need persistence on the client side.

Comment: Good idea. As far as i googled, this is the best solution. It's just a bummer that my country has introduced new rules for websites storing cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use cookie for this purpose. They are not mint for such use.
They are mint to store small amount of data. 
For more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie

PS: Adding this information to answer, so it doesn't mislead others.